# called php functions from a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, global-namespace

It seems I found a error when calling some php functions from a namespace that I can't understand it:

```
<?php
namespace test;
$var = "foo/bar";
echo 'let\'s call \strpos($var, \'o\'):', \strpos($var, 'o');
try{
 echo '<br />let\'s call \unset($var):';
 \unset($var);  //error!
 unset($var);  //correct!
 echo '<br />let\'s call \isset($var):';
 \isset($var);  //error!
 isset($var);  //correct!
}catch(\Exception $e){
 echo 'We have error:', $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Php says: **`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET, expecting T_STRING in global_namespace.php on line 7`**
Not even `try...catch` works and the error is reported ONLY for global functions `isset()` and `unset()`!

I fond it very bizarre, at least!

Comment: That's because namespaces aren't used for functions, they're used for classes. :)

Comment: @Seer Bzzzzzt. Wrong.

Comment: Try/Catch doesn't work because what @Seer said. And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors

Comment: @Seer *"Although any valid PHP code can be contained within a namespace, only four types of code are affected by namespaces: classes, interfaces, functions and constants."* http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day, <3 SO

Answer (score 4):

`isset` and `unset` aren't *functions*, they're *language constructs*. That means they're closer to operators like `+` and `=` than functions, hence do not play by the same rules. There's only one `unset`, you couldn't redefine it as a function if you wanted to.

Further, errors are not exceptions. You can't `catch` an error because it's not `throw`n. Even more so for syntax/parser errors, which happen before any code is even executed.

Comment: Thanks 'deceze' for your answer: still find it very strange how these 'constructs' as you call them are implemented by the php team!

Comment: (Also, I just visited your project Kunststube-Router which I found very interesting as I'm trying to do the same for a project I'm working on-The Front Controller Pattern. Make a contact at your site so one can contact with!)

Comment: *Language constructs* are part of the language itself, not a pre-defined function. Think about it, a regular function cannot `unset` a variable. There's simply no mechanism for a regular function to do so. `unset` is defined by PHP as a reserved keyword and is handled by the PHP interpreter itself. Look through the PHP source code if you want to know the implementation details.

Comment: (And there are various contact details to be found in various places.)