# Catching PHP Parser error when using include

Tags: php, try-catch

I have a file called `functions.php`.

This file consists includes to all the other function files, for example:

```
include_once("user_functions.php");
include_once("foo_functions.php");
```

I would like to catch errors where when I screw a code in one of those files, It wouldn't give the error to the entire system.

For example, if there is a parser error in `foo_functions.php` it will just not include it in `functions.php`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parser errors are fatal errors, so you can't `catch` them.  [See this question and answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors).

What you *can* do if you can run `exec()` is call `php -l thefilename.php` and check the result.  [See the manual for information on how this works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php).  There are a few problems here, however:

- This is *extremely dangerous*, because you are passing information to the command line. You  *absolutely must* filter any user input very carefully, or you would be giving the user very broad access to your system.
- `exec()` is often disabled, as it should be, because of the extremely high security risks of using it incorrectly.
- There's really no good reason to include a file that you haven't already validated for syntax errors. If this is for plugins or something, then I understand your reasoning. If it is code you have control over, however, you should validate before putting it into production.

Comment: This is actually because I am working on a live system and I don't want that by accidentally forgot ; in one function results in the entire users who work on the system to receive a parser error.

I guess the more reasonable solution is to just work on a offline machine and upload the latest version when it's all set, But I am kinda lazy to do that.

Answer (score 13):

As of PHP 7, most eval/include errors, such as ParseError can be catched:

```
try {
  include_once(__DIR__ . '/test.php');
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
  var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder to specify Throwable instead of Exception that I'm so use to using to be able to catch everything possible.

Comment: Tested, works in PHP 7.3 & PHP 7.4 for sure. Just make sure you've wrapped around the ***right*** file and deployed/uploaded the ***right*** file.

Comment: The little gems stackoverflow is famous for, great solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This code can check if file is exist or not, if file exist than include it.

```
<? 
    if(!is_file('user_functions.php')){
        //There is no file user_functions.php . You may use file_put_contents('user_functions.php','<? //content ?>');
    }else{
        //ther is file user_functions.php, so include it.
        include 'user_functions.php'; 
    }
?>
```

And this one help you get syntax errors (PHP 7+ only)

```
<?
    try {
        include('user_functions.php');
    }catch (ParseError $e) {
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
        //syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';'
    }


?>
```

so if you use PHP 7+ you may use:

```
<? 
    if(!is_file('user_functions.php')){
        echo 'Error: file is not exist';
    }else{
        //check errors
        try {
            include('user_functions.php');
        }catch (ParseError $e) {
            echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
            //syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ',' or ';'
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

at the beginning of foo_functions.php ?

Comment: I do want to see errors when they happen.

I just want to be able to catch parsing error, using try catch.
Not sure if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0):

`include()` and `include_once()` return `false` if they fail. You can use this to check if the `include`d files were successful.

```
if (!include('user_functions.php'))
   echo 'user functions failed to include';
if (!include('foo_functions.php'))
   echo 'foo_functions failed to include';
```

By changing the `echo`s to handle your error logic, you should be able to do what you are asking.

Comment: I am referring to a parser error, not if file exist kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I am using feels like a band-aid solution, but it will give you control back.

The idea is to use "eval()" to first check for errors.  Also, ignore errors with the @ in the beginning.  Of course you will need to be careful with eval, so don't ever let users feed anything to it.

```
    // first "eval" the file to see if it contains errors
    $txt = file_get_contents($template_filename);

    // eval starts out in php-mode.  get out of it.
    $txt = '?' . '>' . $txt;
    ob_start();
    $evalResult = @eval($txt);
    ob_end_clean();

    // if there are no errors
    if($evalResult !== FALSE) {
        require($template_filename);
    } else {
        error_log(print_r(error_get_last(), TRUE));
    }
```

Please note that I think "`file_get_contents` + `eval`" = "`require`", or very close to it, so you may be able to just skip the require-part.