# Can't redirect to a maintenance page when serveur return 500 Internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Ive made this .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.php
```

But when i try to access to http://www.mupiz.com/admin/TESTS.php (there's a parse error in it)

The serveur does not redirect to maintenance.php

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have some confusion about custom error handling.

500 is for `Internal Server Error` in Apache before it invokes PHP module. Once PHP module is invoked it is up to the PHP to handle everything. Parse error anyway is not a 500 and even if you make PHP cause 500, Apache's 500 handler won't be invoked.

Comment: Ok how i can have a custom global redirection when there's a fatal error on any page ?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors