# Disabling PHP Error Messages

Tags: php

I am working on my own custom error handler function. Currently I am trying to disable error reporting so it wont display errors to public users. However it is not working.

```
<?php

// Disable error reporting.
ini_set( "error_reporting", 0 );

// Create an error.
echo "hi

?>
```

This returns this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or ${ (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) in C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\sicsportsagency.com\includes\test.php on line 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If there's a syntax error in the script, it never executes the script, so it can't obey the `ini_set()` call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP : Custom error handler - handling parse & fatal errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors)

Comment: @chiwangc great answer, now read the actual question

Comment: chiwangc, the error is intentional to see if the error display was set to off.

Comment: apparently since it is a syntax error you cannot disable the reporting on it. However you can disable Notices and other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* disable error reporting for syntax errors, just for any other sort of error. But there’s a catch.

Using `ini_set` like you’re doing works for errors besides syntax errors because `ini_set` (presumably) runs before the code that has the error in it. With syntax errors in the same file, not so. PHP must parse the whole file before it can even begin to execute the first line of code. If it encounters an error in parsing, even if that error is further along in the file, it’s still parsing and not yet executing: it hasn’t had the chance to run `ini_set`.

**The most straightforward solution would be to edit `php.ini` so the appropriate setting is set before even parsing begins.**

If you can’t do that, you might have to have to put the code that has a potential syntax error in another file, and then the original file can `ini_set` and `require` the second. Since `require` will only parse the required file at the point of execution of the `require`, you can be sure that `ini_set` will run before any parse error in the required script can occur.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not really expecting syntax errors anyways so shouldn't be a problem. Appreciate your input.