# Error reporting is blocked on parse errors

Tags: php, linux, error-handling, error-reporting, php-5.5

I will start by writing that I did see similar questions, and I did try the suggested solutions.

I am running a cli, when I purposely put a parse error in the php file, I get no error in stdOut.
I am using the below configurations:
22527 for error_reporting is
 `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL|E_STRICT);`

```
PHP 5.5.20 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2015 11:20:56) 
php -i | grep error 
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
log_errors => Off => Off
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
track_errors => Off => Off
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
```

ADDITION: If I add my own fatal handler:

```
    function fatal_handler() {
        $error = error_get_last();
        if ($error !== null) {
            echo ("\n\nERROR occured!\nFile [{$error['file']}].\nLine: [{$error['line']}].\nMessage: [{$error['message']}]\n\n");
        }
        exit(1);
    }
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
```

**I do get to see the error in stdio.**

Below is an example to a code (with parse error) that does not produce errors for me

```
class A{
   const AAA = 'aaa';
   static public function Result(A::AAA){

   }
}
```

Comment: Could add an example of the parse error? I get "PHP Parse error:" in STDERR, even with `display_errors => Off => Off`; PHP 5.5.14 (cli).

Comment: why aren't you using apache log or error logs to see the php error? why cli?

Comment: Because I am developing a CLI.

Comment: @AlexBlex see updates

Comment: How are you calling this code? `php myfile.php` or is there a shebang?

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors

Comment: Could not reproduce. I see perfect `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` in STDER. When set `display_errors` to STDOUT, I see it in both streams.

Comment: @miken32 `php ./script.php`

Comment: @AlexBlex Just so I am sure I understand you, how did u set the error to go into stdout?

Comment: @SergeyVidusov This is actually what I currently do, and that way works fine for me.

Comment: Same as you, I assume. I set `display_errors=stdout` in php.ini. Tested with php 5.5 and 5.6 on ubuntu and mac.

Answer (score 0):

The `error_reporting => 22527 => 22527` is equivalent to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`.

Use `-1` or `E_ALL` error level (`E_ALL | E_STRICT` in PHP 5.4) to show all errors.

Set it in the ini file `php.ini`.

```
error_reporting = -1
```

The following won't work, because the code contains a parse error so the `ini_set()` never gets called.

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', -1)

class A 
{
    const AAA = 'aaa';

    static public function Result(A::AAA) 
    {
    }
}
```