# How to catch parse errors in PHP?

Tags: laravel, parsing, exception, handler, fatal-error

I`m writing a light PHP framework for learning purposes and I came up to a problem. In famous frameworks like Laravel for example, all errors are caught and displayed in a custom mode. I know that I can setup custom errorHandler and exceptionHandler for my application like this:

```
set_error_handler([$handler, 'errorHandler']);
set_exception_handler([$handler, 'exceptionHandler']);
```

I can even setup shut_down function in order to catch the fatal errors and in combination with error_get_last() I can throw them as exceptions.

```
register_shutdown_function([$handler, 'shutDownFunction']);
```

Then problem is that I cannot catch parse errors. It seems none of my handlers are catching a parse error. 
Is there a way to do that? Please help.

Comment: You should be able to catch parse errors using the shutdown function, have a look at this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors

Comment: I did that as I mentioned in the original post but if I register it and right after I force the script to stop by writing something random like: "suifgisdfyigsdfyi" it won't catch my error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP : Custom error handler - handling parse & fatal errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors)

Answer (score 0):

In php 7 parser errors handled with `set_error_handler` callback.